# not able to run this code in jupyter notebook init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

Tags: python, offline-mode

I'm trying to make a geographical plot. I'm not able to run the my code in jupyter notebook.

The line of code that won't work is:

```
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

In the context of the rest of the code its:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, 
iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Comment: what is your jupyter and python version. I ran your code successfully.

Comment: Please also describe the current output you're getting (any errors?)

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook 5.7.4 (Through Anaconda)
and there is no error it just shows the blank while I run the code. Blank and it is  a big white space where it is blank

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import plotly.offline as py
from plotly.offline import iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
iplot([Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[4,5,6])])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying now not getting any error but it doesnt show the plot (chart) once i do iplot(choromap). Just a huge blank and no error. Any idea how to fix it

Comment: I am not able to paste the whole code. is there any way I can share the jupyter file.

Comment: You can upload your jupyter file to somewhere (i.e Github, Wetransfer...) and share a link here